# Ch. 10.3.3 Ruby on Rails Tutorial Undefined Method 'any?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to put a feed of all the todo items on the front page when a user is logged in. However, @feed_items is not returning anything, even though feed is working. 
Here's the error:

> undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass

Here's the extracted source:

```
1: <% if @feed_items.any? %>
2:  <ol class="todos">
3:      <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
4:  </ol>
```

Here's my Static Pages Controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

def home
    if signed_in?
        @todo = current_user.todos.build
        @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
end
end
```

Here's my User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation
has_secure_password

before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
before_save :create_remember_token

has_many :todos, :dependent => :destroy

validates :username, :presence => true, length: { maximum: 50 }
validates :password, :presence => true, length: { minimum: 6 }
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, :presence => true, 
        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

def feed
  # This is preliminary. See "Following users" for the full implementation.
  Todo.where("user_id = ?", id)
end

private

def create_remember_token
  self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
end
```

And here is my home page (index.html.erb)

```
% if signed_in? %>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
        </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="span8">
        <h3>Todo Feed</h3>
        <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
    </div>
</div>
<% else %>
<div class="center hero-unit">
    <h1>Welcome to the To Do app!</h1>

    <p>This app allows people to create a to do list for themselves on the web  browser! HELLLZZZ YEEAAAHHH!!!</p>

    <%= link_to "Sign Up Here!", signup_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to "Find your Friends (and other Users) Here!", users_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@feed_items` is nil, and you're trying to call `any?` on it. `Nil` doesn't have that method.

Your controller is "home", but your view is "index". It may be that your controller action isn't being run, and that `@feed_items` isn't being populated as a result. Try renaming `home` to `index` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: So two things. I did have to rename my method to index to correspond to the right page. And then I actually had a Home controller and realized I was putting my method into the wrong controller. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 7):

`Nil` doesn't provide a method `any?`. A quick hack would be to use the `try` method:

```
<% if @feed_items.try(:any?) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that MicropostsController there's `@feed_items = []` before rendering 'static_pages/home' in create action.

Answer (score 1):

See listing 11.48 in the Hartl Rails Tutorial. You need to add the following line of code to the 'create' method in the 'todos'controller: @feed_items = []. I had the same problem until I added this line. Now everything works fine.